# Joomla 1.5 Call for get_path('admin_html') returning Null

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

On line 18 of the admin.categories.php file there is

```
require_once( JApplicationHelper::getPath( 'admin_html' ) );
```

The Helper Library file has not been modified, it still reads

```
function getPath( $varname, $user_option=null )
$check = ( ( $varname == 'mod0_xml' ) || ( $varname == 'mod1_xml' ) );

if ( !$user_option && !$check ) {
    $user_option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
} else {
    $user_option = JFilterInput::clean($user_option, 'path');
}

$result = null;
$name   = substr( $user_option, 4 );
...    
case 'admin_html':
    $path   = DS.'components'.DS. $user_option .DS.'admin.'. $name .'.html.php';
    $result = JApplicationHelper::_checkPath( $path, -1 );
    break;
```

So it's going to wind up building a path '/components//admin..html.php' because the $name and $user_option variables are both empty, right? Then the checkpath fails, which returns null during a failure. None of this code has been modified to my knowledge. So what gives? Anyone point me in the right direction?

The problem this causes is that it throws a fatal error when it can't open a required file. So I can't open the category manager.

Answer (score 0):

So when you select `Category Manager` from the `Content` menu `getPath()` is called with `$varname == 'admin_html'` and `$user_option == null`.

That means that as the first `if()` is true (because `null` equates to `false` and `$check` is `false`) `$user_option` gets set to `com_categories` (the result of the `JRequest::getCmd('option'); line`)

Then `$name` gets set to `'categories'`, so when the `switch()` get to the `admin_html` case it is setting `$path` to `/components/com_categories/admin.categories.html.php` (assuming the local directory separator is set to `/` ).

So as that is the right path and that file is normally included on a J1.5 installation something else has gone wrong (or the file has been removed/deleted)